# How to get the peak that is closest to the current price in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to get the peak price that is closest to the current price, above the current price, and within the last 15 candles

For example, there may be 3 peaks in the last 15 candles. I am trying to sort them to get the peak price that is closest to the price of the most recent candle, and above the most recent candle's price, regardless of which peak happened most recently

I tryed to set that up, but currently it is plotting the close price to the chart and not the target prices

--

How can I get the peak price that is closest to the current price, above the current price, and within the last 15 candles?

--

The Code so far:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="peak", overlay = true)

peak = close[0] < close[1] and close[1] > close[2]

////previouscandle = ta.valuewhen(peak, close[1], 0)
////barssince_last_peak = ta.barssince(peak)

////targetPrice = barssince_last_peak <= 15 and barssince_last_peak > 0 ? previouscandle : na


startprice = close
targetprice = close

//loop through the last 15 candles
for i=0 to 15-1
    
    //if a peak price is greater than the start price set its peak price to the targetpricenew variable
    targetpricenew = ta.valuewhen(peak and close[1] > startprice, close[1], 0)
    
    // if the distance between targetpricenew's peak is less than the distance between the current targetprices's peak 
    if ( targetpricenew - startprice ) < ( targetprice - startprice )

        //Set the targetpricenew peak as the targetprice
        targetprice = targetpricenew


//plot the targetprice
plot(targetprice, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an existing variable like `targetprice` that you want to amend based on the results of your for-loop in this case, you have to use `:=` instead of `=`.

Try replacing `targetprice = targetpricenew` with `targetprice := targetpricenew`.
If you coded your logic-code correctly for what you are trying to do, this will get your script to plot the correct target price!